# Add custom post type settings to wordress default posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, permalinks

When I create custom post types in wordpress I got the following site structure which works perfectly with Permalinks "/%category%/%postname%/":

Preview and category page:
`[main]/animals/ [main]/animals_slug/cat/`

are linking to post detail page:
`[main]/animals/this-is-a-page-about-white-cats`

`[main]/animals_slug/cat/this-is-a-page-about-white-cats (typed in manually)` will be redirected to

`[main]/animals/this-is-a-page-about-white-cats`

I want to do the same for WordPress default posts but I got the following issue.

Posts preview and category page:

`[main]/people/ [main]/people_slug/women/`

only showing post detail page
`[main]/animals_people/women/this-is-a-page-about-a-woman-x`

The page [main]/people/this-is-a-page-about-a-woman-x does not exist and there is no redirection to it. When I change permalinks, to fix this for posts, I got issues with custom post types. How can I prevent those issues? Does anybody have an idea about how to fix this?